# prometheus incorrect values for few targets

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I have Prometheus 2.28.1 version and I installed Node Exporter to few my machines, so my `prometheus.yml` is:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'node-exporter'
    scrape_interval: 60s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['ip1:9100', 'ip2:9100']
```

`ip1` and `ip2` have absolutely different hardware, but all metrics inside prometheus for `ip2` are from `ip1`(`ip1` has 16gb memory, `ip2` only 2gb, so prometheus shows like `ip2` has 16gb memory).

`prometheus_host/targets` shows everything UP and fine. I did `wget` both links `ip1:9100/metrics`, `ip2:9100/metrics` on prometheus host - the information inside correct, but in prometheus for `ip2` not.

[ip1 and ip2 metrics.txt](https://gist.github.com/KonstantinKuklin/007329edf5df5d4ead1d85c140841ab8)

[image: query example]

How I can debug and fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Prometheus server's **only** source of truth for the metrics is `GET`ting the target endpoints, and you assert that the metrics for `ip2` when browsed directly are correct, the evidence suggests that you're incorrectly querying `ip2`'s metrics from within Prometheus.

Please add to your question the evidence that the metric values for `ip2` are incorrect. Perhaps include a screenshot of a query of `ip2` metrics showing the incorrect values.

Please add alongside this a text copy of the metrics when you browse `http://ip2:9100/metrics` directly.